# How to import Live Photos, in full resolution jpg form, from an iPhone 6s to a Windows computer?

Tags: iphone, photos

I've researched this, but can't find the exact answer I'm looking for. My wife has an iPhone 6s and has taken many pictures that are apparently "Live Photos". I tried importing her pictures in to Windows for her to use, but some have the .mov extension, while others are in the traditional .jpg form. She really wants the pictures as full resolution pictures, but I am having trouble getting them for her. Is there a way to batch export all of the pictures she wants into full resolution photos? She has hundreds of them, so doing one at a time would take forever. I tried importing them with a Google program called "Picasa" but most of them are .mov files.

Any help would be appreciated. She is worried she'll have to live with the short movie files.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a matching JPEG for every MOV file, which contains the full resolution photo.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I noticed there were two files, but I was hoping there was someway just to transfer only the Jpg files. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't understand. Why **can't** you just copy the JPEG files? Every live photo has an XXXXX123.jpeg and XXXXX123.mov file. Just copy the .jpeg and you have a full resolution photo. I'm obviously not understanding your question if this isn't the solution.

Comment: @samh I think he'd like a `.bat` file or similar solution to export all of the .jpgs in his folder tree, rather than having to do it one at a time. Seems fair. Could be wrong, YMMV. ;^)

Comment: Right…so don't copy the .mov files? Or delete them later? I'm unclear as to what exactly isn't working. The full-resolution JPEGs are already being exported—he should have too many files, but the question is making it sound like he doesn't have access to what the full res ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Google Photos](http://www.theverge.com/2016/3/7/11174350/google-photos-live-photos-ios-support) instead of Picasa, which Google [no longer supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picasa#Discontinuation).

I personally have not tried this, as I do not have access to a iPhone 6s, but a friend has tried this out for me and says it works. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.copytrans.net/copytransphoto/. It should allow you to transfer only the JPEG.